# Cloudflare SSL not working on Github page

Tags: ssl, github, dns, cloudflare

I am having issues to activate the free Cloudflare SSL on my website. Hosting is on GitHub. My website is working fine. The only problem is the SSL.

My DNS `www` record is set like this:

> [image: DNS]

And the SSL was activated like this:

> [image: SSL]

But still no HTTPS on my page. What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

### Cloudfare SSL on Github pages

[Cloudfare has a detailed article that covers the steps of creating secure and fast Github Pages.](https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/) Follow step 3 to enable SSL (HTTPS)

- the rest of the post is a summary of this step.

> Step 3: Time for SSL

1. Crypto Tab

   - Change SSL to Full
     [image: Change SSL to Full]
2. Page Rules Tab

   - Page Rule to Enforce HTTPS
     [image: Page Rule to Enforce HTTPS]
   - Page Rule non-www to secure www
     [image: Page Rule non-www to secure www]

I tested it a 'few minutes' later and it worked.

Cloudflare debugging article: [Why isn't SSL working for my site](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170566-Why-isn-t-SSL-working-for-my-site-)